# How to fit two random effects separately in lme?

Tags: r, random, nlme

I'm doing Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML in nlme package. And these are codes that work for me:

```
# Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML (intercept and not slope)
x <- lme (DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1*IV2, data=a.frame, random=~1|speaker)
summary(x)

# Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML (slope and no intercept)
x1 <- lme (DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1*IV2, data=a.frame, random=~IV3-1|speaker)
summary(x1)

# Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML (slope and intercept)
x2 <- lme (DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1*IV2, data=a.frame, random=~IV3|speaker)
summary(x2)

#nested random effect
x5 <- lme (DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1*IV2, data=a.frame, random=~1|speaker/item)
summary(x5)
```

What I really would like to do is having a model with both speaker and item as random effects separately. I had tried to use this formula:

```
x4 <- lme (DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1*IV2, data=a.frame, random=~1|speaker + 1|item)
```

However, this formula gives me the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(speaker, 1) : + not meaningful for factors
```

Do you have any idea what this means? And how can I fit both speaker and item as random effects separately?

Comment: Use package lme4. It gives you more flexibility in defining the random part of the model.

Comment: But I can't get the p-value directly from that package as I'm using the new version of R, can I? I have tried that package before and I can't use the 'pval' function. / This package is convenient in that it directly gives me p-value. / I have tried these formula:

Comment: x <- lme (DV ~ IV1, data=a.frame, random=list(~1|speaker, ~1|item))
and this gives me the same results as...
x1 <- lme (DV ~ IV, data=a.frame, random=~1|speaker/item)

Actually the random effects of the second formula should mean 'item nested in speaker' and the first one should mean 'item and speakers as random effects separately. In the output, I don't know why both of them give me the formulas in the summaries as:
Random effects:
Formula: ~1|speaker
Formula: ~1|item %in% speaker
with exactly the same values and everything.

instead of:
 Random effects:
Formula: ~1|speaker
Formula: ~1|item

Comment: if you use `lme4` in conjunction with the `lmerTest` package you can specify the model *and* get the p-values you want (via Satterthwaite or Kenward-Roger approximation).  The chances are reasonably good that `lme` wouldn't be giving you the **correct** p-value anyway ...

Comment: Thanks Ben Bolker. Now it seems that I don't have to use lmerTest anymore, as I do the pairwise comparisons after LMM using lsmeans and this gives me p value directly.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible to include two random effects seperately (one for speaker and one for time) using `lme()` by the following code:

```
x4 <- lme (DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV1*IV2, data=a.frame, random=~ speaker + item -1 | id),
```

with `id` a higher level variable in which both `speaker` and `item` are nested. If you don't have such a variable, you could introduce it as a new variable with value 1 for all observations.