# How to specify correlated crossed random effects in nlme?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I want to specify different random effects in a model using `nlme::lme` (data at the bottom). The random effects are: 1) `intercept` and `position` varies over `subject`; 2)  `intercept` varies over `comparison`. This is straightforward using `lme4::lmer`:

```
lmer(rating ~ 1 + position + 
     (1 + position | subject) + 
     (1 | comparison), data=d)

> ...
Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Std.Dev. Corr 
 comparison (Intercept) 0.31877       
 subject    (Intercept) 0.63289       
            position    0.06254  -1.00
 Residual               0.91458      
 ...
```

However, I want to stick to `lme` as I also want to model the autocorrelation structure (`position` is a time variable). **How can I do the same as above using `lme`?** My try below nests the effect, which is not what I want.

```
lme(rating ~ 1 + position,
random = list( ~ 1 + position | subject,
               ~ 1 | comparison), data=d)

> ...
Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 + position | subject
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev     Corr  
(Intercept) 0.53817955 (Intr)
position    0.04847635 -1    

 Formula: ~1 | comparison %in% subject    # NESTED :(
        (Intercept)     Residual
StdDev:   0.9707665 0.0002465237
...
```

**Note**: There are some similar questions on SO and CV [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/specifying-multiple-separate-random-effects-in-lme), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941303/how-to-include-nested-and-seperate-random-effects-in-one-model-in-nlme-package), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651879/how-to-fit-two-random-effects-seperately-in-lme) but I either did not understand the answer or the suggestion was to use `lmer` which not count here ;)

**Data used in the example**

```r
   d <- structure(list(
  rating = c(
    2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
    2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 
    3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
    5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2), 
  subject = structure(c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), 
    .Label = c(
      "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
      "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
      "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
      "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
      "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
      "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", 
      "61", "62", "63"), 
    class = "factor"), 
  position = c(
    1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
  comparison = structure(c(
    1L, 
    7L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 
    7L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 
    4L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 1L), 
    contrasts = structure(c(
      1, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1), 
      .Dim = c(10L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), NULL)), 
    .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), 
    class = "factor")), 
  .Names = c("rating", "subject", "position", "comparison"), 
  row.names = c(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
    117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 
    228L, 229L, 230L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 
    339L, 340L, 441L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 
    450L, 551L, 552L, 553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L), 
  class = "data.frame")
str(Data)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been meaning to try to figure this out for a while. Without a lot more work I don't think I can get exactly the same model as in `lme4`, but I can get close.

```
## source("SO36643713.dat")
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
```

This is the model you wanted, with a full random-slopes term for `subject` (correlated slope and intercept) and a random-intercept for `comparison`:

```
m1 <- lmer(rating ~ 1 + position + 
               (1 + position | subject) + 
               (1 | comparison), data=d)
```

This is the one I can figure out how to replicate in `lme`: independent intercepts and slopes.  (I don't like these models particularly, but they are in fairly common use as a way for people to simplify too-complex random-effects models.)

```
m2 <- lmer(rating ~ 1 + position + 
               (1 + position || subject) + 
               (1 | comparison), data=d)
```

Results:

```
VarCorr(m2)
##  Groups     Name        Std.Dev.
##  comparison (Intercept) 0.28115 
##  subject    position    0.00000 
##  subject.1  (Intercept) 0.28015 
##  Residual               0.93905
```

For this particular data set, the random slopes are estimated to have zero variance anyway.

Now let's set it up for `lme`. The key (???) insight is that all the terms inside a `pdBlocked()` matrix must be *nested inside the same grouping variable*. For example the crossed-random-effect example on pp. 163ff of Pinheiro and Bates has blocks, rows within blocks, and columns within blocks as the random effects. Since there is no grouping factor within which `comparison` and `subject` are both nested, I'm just going to make up a `dummy` "factor" that includes the whole data set in a single block:

```
d$dummy <- factor(1)
```

Now we can fit the model.

```
m3 <- lme(rating~1+position,
          random=list(dummy =
                pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~subject-1),
                               pdIdent(~position:subject),
                               pdIdent(~comparison-1)))),
          data=d)
```

We have three blocks in the random-effects variance-covariance matrix: one for `subject`, one for the `position`-by-`subject` interaction, and one for `comparison`.  Short of defining a brand-new `pdMat` class, I couldn't figure out an easy way to allow each slope (`position:subjectXX`) to be correlated with its corresponding intercept (`subjectXX`). (You might think you could set this up with a `pdBlocked` structure, but I don't see any way to constrain the variance estimates to be the same across multiple blocks within a `pdBlocked` object.)

The results are pretty much identical, although they're reported differently.

```
vv <- VarCorr(m3)
vv2 <- vv[c("subject1","position:subject1","comparison1","Residual"),]
storage.mode(vv2) <- "numeric"
print(vv2,digits=4)
                   Variance    StdDev
subject1          7.849e-02 2.802e-01
position:subject1 4.681e-11 6.842e-06
comparison1       7.905e-02 2.812e-01
Residual          8.818e-01 9.390e-01
```

Comment: Do you know how `pdIdent(~comparison-1)` can allow the intercept to deviate by `comparison`? I know that `-1` removes the intercept, so what's estimated must be a random slope of `comparison`, which is an integer. As all random effects are grouped by `dummy`, there should be only one possible value, instead of the count of `comparison` levels, of random deviation for this slope. `ranef(m3)` shows only one row of estimated random effects. Is this a desired outcome? Further, I found that `I(comparison + 1)` produces identical outcome while `I(comparison^2)` give very different results.

Comment: `comparison` is a factor, so `~ comparison` will set up a model matrix based on treatment contrasts (first column is an intercept, the others are contrasts between the first level and other levels). `~ comparison - 1` sets up an indicator matrix.  I'm not even sure what `I(comparison^2)` would do ...

Comment: I mistook the variable type. I found the right and lucky solution to correlated crossed random effects in nlme.

Answer (score 1):

Although `nlme` is powerful that includes random effects, error correlation, and variance structure, estimating multiple of these elements can be challenging. Usually random effects and correlated errors are mutually exclusive. Specifying random effects already allows observations in the same group to correlate in a specific pattern. Therefore, a correlation structure of the residuals is often unnecessary in presence of random effects.

In supplement to Ben Bolker's answer, to allow correlated intercepts and slopes of position by subject, we should use `pdSymm()` or `pdLogChol()` that constructs a general positive-definite symmetric variance component matrix in place of `pdIdent()` that coerces a constant diagonal (identical variance among different random-effect predictors) and zero off-diagonal elements (no correlation among different random-effect predictors). `pdSymm()` is the default method inside `pdBlocked()` if only a formula is supplied according to `?pdBlocked`. Outside of `pdBlocked()`, `pdLogChol()` is the default method of random effect structure according to `?reStruct`. I was inspired by the answer to [How to get two random effects crossed with one nested in the other in nlme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342072/how-to-get-two-random-effects-crossed-with-one-nested-in-the-other-in-nlme)

```r
summary(Model <- lme(
  rating ~ 1 + position, random = list(
    one = pdIdent(~ 0 + comparison), 
    subject = pdSymm(~ 1 + position)),
  data = Data %>% mutate(one = factor(1))))
ranef(Model)
"       AIC      BIC    logLik
  187.7118 202.1349 -86.85592
 Formula: ~0 + comparison | one
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
        comparison1 comparison2 comparison3 comparison4 comparison5 comparison6
StdDev:   0.3187715   0.3187715   0.3187715   0.3187715   0.3187715   0.3187715
        comparison7 comparison8 comparison9 comparison10
StdDev:   0.3187715   0.3187715   0.3187715    0.3187715
 Formula: ~1 + position | subject %in% one
 Structure: General positive-definite
            StdDev     Corr  
(Intercept) 0.63288465 (Intr)
position    0.06254075 -1    
Residual    0.91457562       
                Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  3.903085 0.3789931 53 10.298566  0.0000
position    -0.139955 0.0489547 53 -2.858867  0.0061
comparison1 comparison2 comparison3 comparison4 comparison5 comparison6
1   -0.124214   0.1165746   -0.346355   0.3041951 -0.06813102  -0.1990121
  comparison7 comparison8 comparison9 comparison10
1   0.1665042  -0.1454743   0.1223316    0.1735809
Level: subject %in% one 
    (Intercept)     position
1/1 -0.38340091  0.037887119
1/2 -0.73473740  0.072605685
1/3  0.28043574 -0.027712235
1/4  0.04564053 -0.004510136
1/5  0.20881591 -0.020634898
1/6  0.58324613 -0.057635535
pdLogChol reports nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
  message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10) 
pdNatural works"
```

In this case `pdSymm()` converged, but `pdLogChol()` did not, which suggests unreliable model specification. The results are very similar to `lmer`. Note that it is very important to ensure that grouping variables, unless placed after `|` or used as the name of a list element, must be a factor, otherwise it is treated numeric and only one group is formed.

```r
summary(Model <- lmer(
  rating ~ 1 + position + (1 + position | subject) + (1 | comparison), 
  data = Data))
ranef(Model)
"REML criterion at convergence: 173.7
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 comparison (Intercept) 0.101324 0.31831       
 subject    (Intercept) 0.398420 0.63121       
            position    0.003882 0.06231  -1.00
 Residual               0.836809 0.91477       
Number of obs: 60, groups:  comparison, 10; subject, 6
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  3.90306    0.37852  10.311
position    -0.13995    0.04891  -2.861
$comparison
   (Intercept)
1  -0.12403765
2   0.11632288
3  -0.34563369
4   0.30355427
5  -0.06790331
6  -0.19857126
7   0.16608863
8  -0.14527984
9   0.12212718
10  0.17333278
$subject
  (Intercept)     position
1 -0.38245981  0.037753107
2 -0.73275744  0.072331444
3  0.28017368 -0.027656310
4  0.04548482 -0.004489866
5  0.20779079 -0.020511300
6  0.58176795 -0.057427074"
```

The trick in specifying crossed random effects in `nlme` is creating a fake nested structure out of the entire sample as a group, within which individual crossed component without correlated terms inside needs each to be wrapped in `pdIdent()`. Other random effect structure under this fake nest will request more parameters, attempt to estimate a large covariance matrix, and break the estimation routine. The critical challenge is correlation between random effects, which `pdIdent()` cannot suffice. The last component in the random-effect list can be an actual grouping structure, which is necessarily nested within the entire sample. The random-effect component with correlation must be specified as the last element in `random =`  list, as `nlme` assumes a latter element (`subject`) to be nested within the former (`one`). As adding this actual grouping structure breaks the fake one, no further crossed components with correlation can be added. Had there been no correlated random effects, additional crossed dimensions can be added.

```r
summary(Model <- lme(
  rating ~ 1 + position, random = list(one = pdBlocked(list(
    pdIdent(~ 0 + subject), pdIdent(~ 0 + subject:position), 
    pdIdent(~ 0 + comparison)))),
  data = Data %>% mutate(one = factor(1))))
summary(Model <- lme(
  rating ~ 1 + position, random = list(
    one = pdIdent(~ 0 + subject), 
    one = pdIdent(~ 0 + subject:position), 
    one = pdIdent(~ 0 + comparison)),
  data = Data %>% mutate(one = factor(1))))
ranef(Model)
"       AIC      BIC    logLik
  186.6318 198.9944 -87.31588
 Block 1: subject1, subject2, subject3, subject4, subject5, subject6
 Formula: ~0 + subject | one
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
         subject1  subject2  subject3  subject4  subject5  subject6
StdDev: 0.2801523 0.2801523 0.2801523 0.2801523 0.2801523 0.2801523
 Block 2: subject1:position, subject2:position, subject3:position, 
 Formula: ~0 + subject:position | one
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
        subject1:position subject2:position subject3:position subject4:position
StdDev:      7.413267e-06      7.413267e-06      7.413267e-06      7.413267e-06
        subject5:position subject6:position
StdDev:      7.413267e-06      7.413267e-06
 Block 3: comparison1, comparison2, comparison3, comparison4, comparison5,
 Formula: ~0 + comparison | one
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
        comparison1 comparison2 comparison3 comparison4 comparison5 comparison6
StdDev:   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532
        comparison7 comparison8 comparison9 comparison10  Residual
StdDev:   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532    0.2811532 0.9390491
Fixed effects:  rating ~ 1 + position 
                Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  3.898558 0.3016027 58 12.926139  0.0000
position    -0.139132 0.0427492 58 -3.254607  0.0019
    subject1   subject2  subject3    subject4    subject5  subject6
1 -0.1569707 -0.2511531 0.2197589 -0.01569707 -0.01569706 0.2197589
  subject1:position subject2:position subject3:position subject4:position
1     -3.832871e-10     -2.115069e-10      1.345151e-09     -3.438398e-10
  subject5:position subject6:position comparison1 comparison2 comparison3
1     -7.796287e-10      3.731118e-10  -0.1145524  0.08768834   -0.271683
  comparison4 comparison5 comparison6 comparison7 comparison8 comparison9
1   0.2367088  -0.0370021  -0.1535825   0.1186084  -0.1388825   0.1104984
  comparison10
1    0.1621986"
```

As both `lmer` and `lme` with random-effects correlation report an estimate of the correlation coefficient at its boundary, they are over specified and will benefit from a simpler specification. Without random-effects correlation, many crossed terms can be estimated, either in `pdBlocked()` or a list of crossed components named by the fake grouping variable. From the above summary, the standard deviation of `position` is very small, compared with those of the other two random effects, thus worth dropping. It is fine to reuse the same grouping variable in multiple nested structures to mimic crossed random effects, as group `one` nested within `one` has still only one unique level. However, it can be a challenge for postestimation tools to identify the correct level.

```r
summary(Model <- lme(
  rating ~ 1 + position, random = list(
    one = pdIdent(~ 0 + subject), 
    one = pdIdent(~ 0 + comparison)),
  data = Data %>% mutate(one = factor(1))))
ranef(Model)
intervals(Model)
"       AIC     BIC    logLik
  184.6318 194.934 -87.31588
 Formula: ~0 + subject | one
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
         subject1  subject2  subject3  subject4  subject5  subject6
StdDev: 0.2801524 0.2801524 0.2801524 0.2801524 0.2801524 0.2801524
 Formula: ~0 + comparison | one %in% one
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
        comparison1 comparison2 comparison3 comparison4 comparison5 comparison6
StdDev:   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532
        comparison7 comparison8 comparison9 comparison10  Residual
StdDev:   0.2811532   0.2811532   0.2811532    0.2811532 0.9390491
                Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  3.898558 0.3016027 58 12.926139  0.0000
position    -0.139132 0.0427492 58 -3.254607  0.0019
Level: one 
    subject1   subject2 subject3    subject4    subject5 subject6
1 -0.1569707 -0.2511531 0.219759 -0.01569707 -0.01569707 0.219759
Level: one %in% one 
  comparison1 comparison2 comparison3 comparison4 comparison5 comparison6
1  -0.1145525  0.08768836   -0.271683   0.2367089 -0.03700211  -0.1535825
  comparison7 comparison8 comparison9 comparison10
1   0.1186084  -0.1388825   0.1104984    0.1621986
 Random Effects:
  Level: one            lower      est.    upper
sd(0 + comparison) 0.07356078 0.2801524 1.066946
  Level: one            lower      est.    upper
sd(0 + comparison) 0.07356078 0.2801524 1.066946"
summary(Model <- lme(
  rating ~ 1 + position, random = list(
    one = pdIdent(~ 0 + subject), 
    two = pdIdent(~ 0 + comparison)),
  data = Data %>% mutate(one = factor(1), two = factor(2))))
ranef(Model)
intervals(Model)
"Approximate 95% confidence intervals
 Fixed effects:
                 lower       est.       upper
(Intercept)  3.2948350  3.8985584  4.50228184
position    -0.2247037 -0.1391318 -0.05356001
 Random Effects:
  Level: one         lower      est.    upper
sd(0 + subject) 0.07356078 0.2801524 1.066946
  Level: two           lower      est.    upper
sd(0 + comparison) 0.0709893 0.2811532 1.113508
 Within-group standard error:
    lower      est.     upper 
0.7621853 0.9390491 1.1569539 "
```

With random intercepts by `subject` and `comparison` crossed, random slopes and correlation removed, the above model has the smallest AIC and BIC among all tested. By renaming the fake nesting variable into different names for different crossed terms, `intervals()` no longer confuses the random-effect term to extract. If the same nesting variable is used in multiple layers, confidence intervals of only the bottom layer of the nesting structure is reported. Using the `pdBlocked()` approach does not suffer from this variable-naming issue.

```r
summary(Model <- lme(
  rating ~ 1 + position, random = list(one = pdBlocked(list(
    pdIdent(~ 0 + subject), pdIdent(~ 0 + comparison)))),
  data = Data %>% mutate(one = factor(1))))
intervals(Model)
" Random Effects:
  Level: one            lower      est.    upper
sd(0 + subject)    0.07362742 0.2801524 1.065980
sd(0 + comparison) 0.07107054 0.2811532 1.112235"
```

In summary, crossing by nesting allows "arbitrary levels of crossed and nested random effects. However, only one [component with] correlation for the crossed random effects can be estimated." Internally, terms like `pdIdent(~ 0 + subject)` will add to the design matrix six columns of indicators of `subject = 1`, ..., `subject = 6` since the intercept term is omitted. Each column is allowed to have a random slope (instead of a random intercept) that may be different from other columns. Hence, ensuring `subject` is a factor not an integer is critical, otherwise only one column of integers is produced to have one single group deviation instead of six deviations by subject. Nevertheless, `pdIdent()` requests that all these six columns to have identical variance of the random slope. Therefore, only one parameter (the standard deviation of the random slope of subject indicators) is estimated in `summary()`, while six different evaluations of this random effect is given in `ranef()`.

Comment: Thanks, Jerry. TBH, I have not worked with these models in years an. Thus, it is currently beyond me to decide which answer should be the accepted one. @Ben Bolker: What do you think?