# multiple random effects in nlme

Tags: r, random, nlme

I need to include one more random effect in my `lme` model. However, these 2 random effects are not related, therefore cannot be nested.

I am not sure how to write the code for this. I've tried the following:

```
modelA <- lme(FT~ Init.Age + Sex + Status, random= (1|Patient) + (1|Site), data = data, na.action = na.omit)

modelB <- lme(FT~ Init.Age + Sex + Status, random= list (~1|Patient, ~1|Site), data = data, na.action = na.omit)
```

only model B works. But it gives me exactly the same results as `random= ~1|Patient` and I think that cannot be correct.  The results are the following:  [image]

Thanks for your help! 
lil

Comment: `random = ~ (1|Patient) + (1|Site)`. Also for this kind of simple structure it might be beneficial to use `lme4` (for speed) for which the random effects are directly included in the `formula` term: `formula = FT ~Init.age + Sex + Status + (1|Patient) + (1|Site)` other than that used in exactly the same manner.

Comment: Dear Oliver, thanks! The problem is that I need p values, and lme4 does not provide me with them.
The thing is: I need to control by Site (patients can belong to site1 or site2). As I think Site has an influence in FT. Could I convert site (Factor) into an integer and put it as a fixed effect, rather than put it as a random effect? would that be right? 
Thanks!

Comment: `random = ~ (1|Patient) + (1|Site)` gives me the following error: 

Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) : 
  invalid formula for groups

Comment: Alrighty i took a bit of time, and checked up. [This sigma question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2018q2/026750.html) [and this SE question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/specifying-multiple-separate-random-effects-in-lme) talks about the same problem. Basically it seems you are forced to use a nested structure `random = list(Patient = ~ 1, Site = ~1)`. For `lme4` Sattertwaithe (spelling?) approximations can be obtained by loading the `lmerTest` package.

Comment: oops! I have forgotten to reply but this actually worked!! Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem, i am glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a popular learning opportunity on `nlme` that assumes nested random effects intrinsically. To specify crossed random intercepts by two factors, we need

```r
lme(FT ~ Init.Age + Sex + Status, random = list(one = pdBlocked(
  pdIdent(~ 0 + Patient), pdIdent(~ 0 + Site))), 
  data = data |> transform(one = factor(1)))
```

Note that we must code both `Patient` and `Site` as factors instead of numeric integers. See more details at [How to specify different random effects in nlme vs. lme4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643713/how-to-specify-different-random-effects-in-nlme-vs-lme4/78014278) and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274777/modelling-random-structure-in-lmer-and-nlmelme/613085.