# two random effects on the intercept in the lme() function

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I'm trying to introduce two random effects into the intercept using the `lme()` function from the `nlme` package. The idea is to rewrite the `barleyprogeny1.lmer` model in `nlme()`.

I found some information in this post: [multiple random effects in nlme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224493/multiple-random-effects-in-nlme) and https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2018q2/026750.html,
and then I decided to adjust the models based on the information and they looked like this:

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
barleyprogeny1.lme <- lme(yield_g_m2 ~ 1,
                           random = list(fblock = ~ 1, fline = ~1),
                           method="REML",
                           dataexperiment)
barleyprogeny1.lmer <- lmer(yield_g_m2 ~ 1 + 
                            (1|fblock) + (1|fline), 
                            REML=TRUE,
                            data = dataexperiment) 
barleyprogeny2.lme <- lme(yield_g_m2 ~ 1,
                          random = ~1|fblock,
                          method="REML",
                          data = dataexperiment)                         
barleyprogeny2.lmer <- lmer(yield_g_m2 ~ 1 + 
                          (1|fblock), 
                          REML=TRUE,
                          data = dataexperiment)
```

However, when comparing whether these models are the same, see that there is a significant difference:

```
all.equal(REMLcrit(barleyprogeny1.lmer), c(-2*logLik(barleyprogeny1.lme))) 
"Mean relative difference: 0.021192723770312"

all.equal(fixef(barleyprogeny1.lme), fixef(barleyprogeny1.lmer))
"Mean relative difference: 0.016793324438639"
```

Furthermore, when I compare, for example, the difference between the Log-Likelihood of both models `barleyprogeny1.` in `nlme` vs. `lme4`, they are quite different,
what seems to me is that the effect `fline = ~1` in `barleyprogeny1.lme` is ignored:

```
-2*logLik(barleyprogeny2.lmer)
'log Lik.' 1912.0625636471 (df=3)   #In this case they are equal
-2*logLik(barleyprogeny2.lme)
'log Lik.' 1912.0625636472 (df=3)
#################################
-2*logLik(barleyprogeny1.lmer)
'log Lik.' 1872.3816955801 (df=4)   # In this case they are not equal.
-2*logLik(barleyprogeny1.lme)
'log Lik.' 1912.0625636471 (df=4)
```

The fact that I am interested in the `lme()` function is due to some possibilities that this function allows in contrast to `lmer()`. The post I mention at the beginning of this thread is from 2019. Is there any implementation or idea for this fix?

The data is here:

```
structure(list(block = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), line = c(2L, 39L, 41L, 4L, 79L, 76L, 78L, 
35L, 25L, 67L, 17L, 30L, 73L, 64L, 72L, 44L, 18L, 82L, 29L, 23L, 
38L, 31L, 40L, 57L, 63L, 83L, 36L, 66L, 10L, 13L, 62L, 81L, 43L, 
26L, 45L, 12L, 24L, 51L, 6L, 14L, 80L, 46L, 42L, 47L, 37L, 27L, 
54L, 32L, 70L, 9L, 8L, 77L, 22L, 11L, 58L, 19L, 49L, 28L, 50L, 
74L, 7L, 68L, 59L, 16L, 33L, 53L, 75L, 20L, 61L, 1L, 71L, 55L, 
69L, 60L, 21L, 65L, 34L, 5L, 48L, 56L, 3L, 15L, 52L, 64L, 27L, 
29L, 68L, 16L, 33L, 67L, 51L, 66L, 50L, 36L, 80L, 17L, 26L, 63L, 
74L, 56L, 81L, 43L, 79L, 14L, 32L, 70L, 41L, 31L, 71L, 65L, 7L, 
58L, 69L, 34L, 11L, 44L, 49L, 54L, 72L, 9L, 23L, 48L, 59L, 78L, 
61L, 45L, 18L, 19L, 35L, 6L, 40L, 8L, 1L, 10L, 42L, 46L, 37L, 
60L, 38L, 13L, 24L, 39L), yield_g_m2 = c(483.33, 145.84, 321.84, 
719.14, 317.63, 344.48, 260.02, 374.28, 428.61, 407.25, 551.84, 
353.29, 355.3, 647.92, 165.76, 517.52, 366.24, 251.3, 606.37, 
605.75, 641.42, 166.75, 410.87, 181.97, 562.9, 280.44, 800.35, 
687.92, 764.88, 541.15, 730.48, 315.63, 678.46, 580.22, 519.88, 
436.59, 671.22, 692.55, 849.66, 910.76, 487.86, 724.01, 793.43, 
192.43, 895.3, 731.87, 809.41, 669.16, 996.19, 774.84, 636.45, 
357.94, 340.65, 644.83, 521.67, 622.72, 830.57, 679.92, 721.13, 
489.31, 907.38, 325.96, 553.46, 210.71, 770.23, 559.14, 617.33, 
632.46, 611.52, 717.78, 595.86, 555.29, 467.24, 572.9, 514.62, 
818.74, 673.43, 798.99, 786.06, 522.61, 873.04, 600.06, 603.04, 
681.64, 762.42, 932.33, 385.47, 240, 846.85, 702.58, 746.11, 
846.05, 885.67, 1054.7, 478.12, 959.25, 639.39, 755.9, 551.41, 
435.62, 303.72, 836.82, 439.17, 934.72, 836.95, 904.9, 538, 226.12, 
569.61, 713.43, 820.08, 435.34, 378.89, 639.11, 516.84, 873.18, 
823.25, 859.36, 258.59, 587.07, 817.51, 645.1, 634.58, 260.26, 
472.44, 575.76, 265.37, 423.76, 554.69, 755.05, 568.31, 299.92, 
591.19, 756.63, 552.53, 627.25, 552.7, 284.72, 540.68, 475.1, 
463.22, 212.66), fblock = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    fline = structure(c(2L, 39L, 41L, 4L, 79L, 76L, 78L, 35L, 
    25L, 67L, 17L, 30L, 73L, 64L, 72L, 44L, 18L, 82L, 29L, 23L, 
    38L, 31L, 40L, 57L, 63L, 83L, 36L, 66L, 10L, 13L, 62L, 81L, 
    43L, 26L, 45L, 12L, 24L, 51L, 6L, 14L, 80L, 46L, 42L, 47L, 
    37L, 27L, 54L, 32L, 70L, 9L, 8L, 77L, 22L, 11L, 58L, 19L, 
    49L, 28L, 50L, 74L, 7L, 68L, 59L, 16L, 33L, 53L, 75L, 20L, 
    61L, 1L, 71L, 55L, 69L, 60L, 21L, 65L, 34L, 5L, 48L, 56L, 
    3L, 15L, 52L, 64L, 27L, 29L, 68L, 16L, 33L, 67L, 51L, 66L, 
    50L, 36L, 80L, 17L, 26L, 63L, 74L, 56L, 81L, 43L, 79L, 14L, 
    32L, 70L, 41L, 31L, 71L, 65L, 7L, 58L, 69L, 34L, 11L, 44L, 
    49L, 54L, 72L, 9L, 23L, 48L, 59L, 78L, 61L, 45L, 18L, 19L, 
    35L, 6L, 40L, 8L, 1L, 10L, 42L, 46L, 37L, 60L, 38L, 13L, 
    24L, 39L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
    "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
    "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
    "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
    "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", 
    "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
    "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
    "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", 
    "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83"), class = "factor"), plot = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
    39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
    51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
    63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
    75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
    53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
    "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
    "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
    "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
    "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", 
    "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", 
    "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
    "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", 
    "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -142L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard term for what you want is *crossed random effects*, which are known to be a pain to implement in `lme`.

Adapting from [this CV question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551690/how-do-i-specify-crossed-random-intercepts-in-lme) and ultimately from a [2003 conversation on r-help between Doug Bates and Peter Dalgaard](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-October/041272.html):

```r
dataexperiment$int <- 1  ## create dummy variable
barleyprogeny1.lme <- lme(yield_g_m2 ~ 1,
                          random = list(int = pdIdent(form = ~ 0 + factor(fblock)), 
                                        fline = ~1),
                          method="REML",
                          dataexperiment)

barleyprogeny1.lmer <- lmer(yield_g_m2 ~ 1 + 
                            (1|fblock) + (1|fline), 
                            REML=TRUE,
                            data = dataexperiment)
```

Comparing results:

```r
VarCorr(barleyprogeny1.lme)

                Variance                    StdDev   
int =           pdIdent(0 + factor(fblock))          
factor(fblock)1    14.61884                   3.82346
factor(fblock)2    14.61884                   3.82346
fline =         pdLogChol(1)                         
(Intercept)     30645.45039                 175.05842
Residual        13221.74805                 114.98586

VarCorr(barleyprogeny1.lmer)

 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 fline    (Intercept) 175.0585
 fblock   (Intercept)   3.8228
 Residual             114.9858
```

Not identical, but the relative difference is only about 2e-6; the log-likelihoods are equivalent up to the standard tolerance of `all.equal()`.

From the previous answer: because `lme` can only do *nested* random effects you have to

> ... [trick] lme by creating a group with a single level. The model is still nested but now it is the single level group that is part of the nesting which is no problem.

> The crossed random effect is incorporated by treating the random effect for the one group as a parameter for a slope instead of an intercept.

The `pdIdent` specification says that the covariance matrix for the `fblock` random effect should be homogeneous and diagonal ("a multiple of the identity positive-definite matrix", according to the documentation); this mimics what would happen if you could specify an intercept term `1|fline`.

Comment: Nice Ben Bolker! I can't assign you the +50, they ask for 24h! I'll do that soon.